# keeping a reliable php/postgres connection on debian

Tags: postgresql, symfony, debian

I'm attempting to run a Debian VM locally with vagrant. I'm using php 5.5 with apache and postgresql 9.1. Randomly my Symfony app seems to not be able to make a connection or something because i'll get an exception thrown saying that it couldn't find my table. I'll refresh the page a couple of times and then it'll find it and display the data. I don't know enough about server admin to debug this myself. Is there a connection timeout setting i can set somewhere that may alleviate this? or can you suggest another idea to determine/fix the problem?

The connection settings Symfony is using

```
database_driver: pdo_pgsql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 5432
database_name: appDB
database_user: root
database_password: root
```

My postgres database structure

```
               List of relations
 Schema |        Name        |   Type   | Owner
--------+--------------------+----------+-------
 public | migration_versions | table    | root
 public | users              | table    | root
 public | users_id_seq       | sequence | root
(3 rows)
```

My postgres permissions

```
 Schema |        Name        |   Type   | Access privileges | Column access privileges
--------+--------------------+----------+-------------------+--------------------------
 public | migration_versions | table    | root=arwdDxt/root |
 public | users              | table    | root=arwdDxt/root+|
        |                    |          | =arwdDxt/root     |
 public | users_id_seq       | sequence | root=rwU/root    +|
        |                    |          | =rwU/root         |
(3 rows)
```

[image]

Comment: This would be a different error message if it was disconnected. Are you sure there isn't something that drops/recreates this `users` table, or you haven't a movable `search_path` ?

Comment: could you elaborate on the movable `search_path`? I haven't heard of that before

Comment: see [The Schema Search Path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) in the doc